# ASP.Net Cache object is not sharing between different PCs

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-applications

I have a ASP.Net 4.0 web application and I extract and put the data into the cache for 10 minutes by using the following code:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

if (System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["MyStudents"] != null)
{
    students = (List<students >)System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["MyStudents"];
    Response.Write("Get From Cache");
}
else
{
    students = MyClass.GetStudents();
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("MyStudents", students, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), TimeSpan.Zero);
    Response.Write("Get From DB");
}
```

It works only for the single user or PC.  If I use another pc to browse the same page, it connects to the database at the first load.  But it uses the cache for the next time.  The problem is that it's not sharing the cache object between different session.

Could you pls advise me where I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: are you hitting from the another PC or browser within the 10 minutes since you hit the first time ? Cache has nothing to do with the PC or browser for sure . it is not Session and it should be shared across each other until it expires. Your key of the cache is same as you have shown in the code .

Comment: Yes, I am using the same Cache Key.  I browsed the page with my PC.  Then I used my spare PC to browse the same page within a minute.  According to theory, the Cache should be shared within the same Application.  It's very strange and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/4y13wyk9.aspx) you need to use `Cache.NoSlidingExpiration` rather than `TimeSpan.Zero` to disable the sliding expiration.